# syntax error xml linq query

Tags: .net, xml, linq

i want query a file xml with linq,
i want get all descendat of SubLayers which has the name SubLayer and has 
an attribute which is called "Where"

how do i write this query in linq ?
i wrote it in this way:

```
 var query3 = from c in xmlFile.Descendants("SubLayers").Elements("SubLayer").Where(c.Attribute("where" != null))
 select c;
```

but it say that i can't use

```
 c
```

in the

```
 where condition.
```

how do i write it ??

Comment: i wrote it in this way:  from c in xmlFile.Descendants("SubLayers").Elements("SubLayer") where c.Attribute("where") != null
                                         select c;  it same to be good

Comment: not so sure if it is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query3 = from c in xmlFile.Descendants("SubLayers").Elements("SubLayer") where c.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name == "where") 
 select c;
```

Comment: SORRY MAN IT WORKED IT WAS JUST "Where" not "where" it is ok